# How to extend the Visual Studio web publish pipeline?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, publishing, webdeploy

I'd like to tweak how visual studio **publish** a website to a **package**, generally the package is created by picking up the whole list of files inside the **root directory**, compile, perform optimizations and so on.

In my case the problem is that I'm developing a SPA using **angular.js** and **Grunt** to **build** (optimize) the **app**, the tasks are configured to drop the "optimized" version of the site into "dist" which is located bellow the root folder, which is the typical scenario for this workflow using grunt.

These are the details for scenario, 
The folder structure is the following:

- /root

  - bower_components

    - lib1 <- angularjs, jquery, etc
    - lib2
  - module1

    - directives
    - partials

      - /page1

        - page1.html <- view
        - page1.js <- controller
        - page1.less <- obviously a less file
        - page1.spec.js <- test
  - module2
  - module3
  - etc, etc, etc

After **build** on **Grunt** I get the optimized version like this

- /root

  - bower_components
  - module1
  - module2
  - module3
  - **dist** <- how can I pick up this folder instead of the content in root?

    - bower_components <- minified versions
    - app.min.js
    - app.min.css
    - index.html

I'd like to have the **package** for deployment as the following:

- /root

  - libraries (dlls) <- server side libraries
  - bower_components <- minified versions of libraries
  - app.min.js       <- from dist but in the root folder of the published package
  - app.min.css
  - index.html

I know that there is a .pubxml file configuration, Is it possible to do it by modifying this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did my own research and I found a way to do it.

you need to create a wpp.targets file in your root, the name should be [projectName].wpp.targets for example.

then in the file you'll need to setup msdeploy with the following instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
          <BuildDependsOn Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
            gruntBuild
          </BuildDependsOn>
          <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
           foldername1, foldername2
          </ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
          <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
           filename.extension, filename2, filename3, etc
          </ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
          <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            CustomCollectFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
          </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
          <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
            CustomCollectFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
          </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
        </PropertyGroup>

      <!--
        you can try to run the grunt build for me it takes too long and the visual studio just gets freeze so I run the grunt task before doing the deploy, but it's up to you 
        <Target Name="gruntBuild">
        <Message Text="=== buil on publish ===" Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
          <Binaries Include="*.dll;*.exe"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Exec Command="bower install" />
        <Exec Command="grunt build" />
      </Target>-->

      <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
        <Message Text="=== CustomCollectFiles ===" Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
          <CustomFiles Include="dist\**\*.*" />
          <FilesForPackagingFromProject   Include="%(CustomFiles.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
          </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
      </Target>
    </Project>
```